# Mootools Asset with

Tags: php, javascript, http-headers, mootools

I got an understanding problem with the Asset object from the mootools library. I use the following code to initialize an [Asset](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Utilities/Assets#Asset%3aAsset-image)  object.

```
this.preloader = new Asset.image(src, {
    'onerror': function(){
    // do something
    },
    'onload': function(){
        this.store('loaded', true);
    }
});
```

If I use an image url as `src` parameter without parameters (normal image file on disk) like this:

```
http://test.local/images/picture1.jpg
```

it works.

If I use an image url  as `src` parameter from a php script that generates an image by using the function [imagejpeg()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php):

```
http://test.local/index.php/de/galerie/directory1/index.php?view=image&amp;format=raw&amp;type=img&amp;id=2774
```

It shows me a broken link later on.

Question: Why does the Asset react different? is there an option I am missing?

Thanks a lot for any help!
Spikey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was elsewhere. I can confirm that the Asset object supports output of the mentioned php function that generates a jpeg stream and it also accepts URL parameters in the given `src` parameter.

I found the other problem by monitoring the processed http request/responses and I saw that there was an incoming second image stream that got wrong parameters and delivered the "broken image reference".

At least this post maybe helps someone else to drop the "image stream bug thesis" earlier than I.

regards
Spikey